# Finding mechanical advantage and torque of a compound sprocket system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, machine-design

I was looking through some stuff on simple mechanisms, and the calculation of mechanical advantage and torque.

I wanted to check if compound sprocket systems can be treated in a similar way to compound gear systems.

For example if you want to find the (ideal) mechanical advantage of a sprocket-and-chain system, like on a bicycle, it's pretty straightforward to use the number of teeth on the output sprocket divided by the input (if I got that backwards tell me!) so I would say

$$ IMA  = \frac{n_{out}}{n_{in}} $$

So far so good. If I have a 6-tooth sprocket as my input (driven sprocket) and a 30-tooth sprocket as the output I have an IMA ~5. (We'll not get into figuring out friction, slip, all that yet).

But what if, to my 30-tooth sprocket, I attach another 6-tooth sprocket on the same axle, and a second chain that goes to a second 30-tooth sprocket. The idea would be similar to a compound gear train. If it were a gear train, my gear ratio would be

$(\frac{30}{6} \times \frac{30}{6}) = \frac{900}{36} = 25)$

and I would expect an IMA to be about that, so my torque generated would be 25 times whatever the input torque is (and with the concomitant reduction in speed).

But does the same apply to sprockets as to gear trains? That is the question. I hope this doesn't seem stupidly simplistic and I checked around on this forum to see if anyone had answered this already, but I didn't find anything that spoke to my specific situation. (if I missed it though, due to bad search terms, by all means tell me). An just so anyone reading this knows, my instinct is to treat compound sprockets the same way I would a gear train. But I just wanted to be sure.

Also be aware, I am not getting into all the other factors one would use in a real word situation; I know friction, slip, tension, etc. play a role. I am starting with a very simplified situation *before* I get into that level of detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have it right

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure, it was one of those things that *intuitively* sounded correct but we all know where intuition can lead in engineering and physics :-)